# Select from a matrix based on the values of 2 distinct variables

Tags: r, matrix, selection, logical-operators

Suppose I have a matrix with values of a response variable as one column and 2 characteristics such as Gender and location as the other two columns.

How do I select the particular values of the response based on specific values of both gender and location?

For example, I know

> dataset$response[gender=="Male"]

will select all the Males. But say I want to select the response values from males that are from location=='SE' as well. I don't know how to do this.

Thanks a lot!

p.s. (I tried looking for this on the internet, but it is difficult finding help for the [] operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logical 'and':

```
dataset$response[dataset$gender=="Male" & dataset$location=="SE"]
```

More information on logical operators in R can be found by using `help("&")`.

Answer (score 3):

If `dataset` is a data-frame, simply use `subset`:

```
subset( dataset, gender == 'Male' & location == 'SE' )$response
```